# Third-party referenced dll not been copied to build out

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have a thirdparty .net dll being reference and used by my dll/class library project “A”. My console app project “B” references project “A”.

My problem is the thirdparty dll is not being copied to the build out for console app project “B”.

What’s the problem here? The thirdparty dll ref’d in my dll/class library is set to LocalCopy=true.

I'm using vs2008 and .net 3.5.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project B needs to explicitly reference the third party DLL, basically. References aren't *assumed* to be transitive. (If you try to use any classes in project A which expose types from the third party library, you'll even get a compilation error.)

It can be a pain, but at least it makes it clear what you're really dragging in.

Comment: Either way, you can build your console app B and library project A at the same time with a common OutDir, your third party dll will be here.<br /> Note also that if you had referenced dll and not project, it would have copied the third party library if it was in the same directory as your proj A dll.

Comment: I have a similar setup where Proj B adds a PROJECT REFERENCE of Proj A. Shouldn't this be enough to copy all of Proj A's outputs (including references to Proj B's outdir?)

Comment: @lysergic-acid: Why would project A's output include a reference to project B's output directory? But no, in general when you add a reference to a project I believe that's *just* to the assembly created by the project.

Comment: I have a WCF service project that references some DLL (system.data.sqlite). I have a host project (console) that references the service. This means i dont get the data.sqlite dll's copied over to the host output dir...

Comment: @lysergic-acid: No, you wouldn't. The SQLite assembly isn't part of the project *output* - and if you need it in another project, you have to add the reference to that project too, it's as simple as that.