# Problem with custom control that depends on several other dlls

Tags: c#, .net, dll, controls, reference

I have created a custom button (you know, with all that eye-candy stuff etc). That control is based on several other dlls because i want to make set of controls that have the same base (i had already created progressbar, label and button).

But there's a problem - when i import reference to my button to some other project (so i can use my button as a regular button) i have to manually import all those dlls my button depends on! Is there a way to automatically import all needed dlls (references) whenever i import my button?
You know - when i drag my control from toolbox on to form, I want that C# automatically loads ALL dlls that added control depends on. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the reference -> Properties -> set Copy Local = True

If even with this, the dlls is not being copied, them you're probably referencing them in the GAC. You'll have to remove those GAC references...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: "Copy Local" is set to true :\ Any idea how to fix those GAC references?

Comment: A research returned me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776658/third-party-referenced-dll-not-been-copied-to-build-out